# Google BigQuery bq command line SDK to extend or enhance bq command line

Tags: google-bigquery, bq

I am interested in extending the bq command-line utility from BigQuery with a plugin or wrapper around it. The challenge is the Google cloud storage URI changes dynamically and I would like to make sure that it is handled well before the bq utility is being run at scheduled times.
So the question is does bq which is a python based tool have any SDK with which I can extend its functionality.

I combed everywhere but I could not find any information regarding it.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

bq command line utility code base is archived Google Code, I coulnot find the latest repo.
https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-bigquery-tools/

If you really want to extand, the source code is available in google-cloud-sdk folder. If you installed the google cloud sdk in your local machine, you can see the bq source code in google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bq.py